# In a SWT program, how to start a thread which is able to update the UI without blocking

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

I have a working Java application (about 10k loc) which started as a command line program. A few months ago I "enhanced" it to be a very simple unthreaded SWT application, which added very little but was a step towards what I am trying to do now.

I am trying to make the invocation of the worker code to be run in a thread.  I have read a good many recommendations on the internet, and have come up with a prototype:

```
package myapp;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class Console {
    Display display;
    Shell shell;
    Text text;

    private void process() {
        display = new Display();
        shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        shell.setLocation(new Point(80, 80));

        text = new Text(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.READ_ONLY);

        shell.open();

        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Worker(text).work();
            }
        });

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }

        display.dispose();
    }

    class Worker {
        Text text;

        public Worker(Text t) {
            text = t;
        };

        void work() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                text.append("hello " + i + "\n");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Console().process();
    }
}
```

The Worker class represents the bulk of my application,

When I run this, the output lines start appearing every second, as expected, but when I try to interact with the window in any way (eg to move it), at first the window is unresponsive, but then the output stops displaying, the window is movable, and nothing further appears in the window until the end of processing, when everything remaining is displayed all at once, and the end result LOOKS correct.

If I leave the window untouched, it displays correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ahem.  That's what I have. Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {...}

Answer (score 3):

You need to start your worker in its own thread. As soon you get a result you can insert it into your gui by calling display.asyncExec from the worker-thread.

there is a snippet doing something similar here:
[Snippet7](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet7.java)

In this Snippet they are doing it by syncExec, which blocks your worker until the display-thread executed the runnable. This can be easier to synchronize. Or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710992/swt-periodically-update-gui?rq=1)

Comment: I like this. Although it appears the snippet is almost exactly like the code block I proposed, although it uses `syncExec` instead of `asyncExec`. That could be the underlying problem.

Comment: No its not! Look carefully ! they start their own thraead (line 38 - 56). your are executing your worker in the displaythread.

Comment: no, the first code block is from the OP. the second code block executes only the `append()` method from inside the GUI thread.

Comment: But don't put put everything in the asyncExec-runnable, just put the code to update your GUI there and do the calculation in the runnable of your new thread.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that you are not the OP.

Comment: it's all good. as long as the OP understands that you should only execute the actual GUI update from inside the GUI thread, and never use a `Thread.sleep()` inside a GUI thread, because it's a blocking method call.

Comment: I am the OP.The thread.sleep was just an artificial thing to make the thing run for a few seconds so I could test interaction with the window.  I have removed it and the problem is still there. All the app needs to do is to pass its sysout and syserr to the Text area. Later I may make the Text a StyledText and add colors, but one thing at a time.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be the trouble spot. `Worker` sleeps the thread.

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Worker(text).work();
        }
    });
```

It appears to me that you are creating a new `Worker` which looks like it calls `Thread.sleep()` which will `Block` the thread. In this case, it's your GUI thread since it's being executed from inside it!

Fix this by removing that offending `Thread.sleep()`. I try to steer clear of `Thread.sleep()` in production code.

To keep your timing, you can try moving the `asyncExec` into your `Worker` (untested)

```
class Worker {
    Text text;

    public Worker(Text t) {
        text = t;
    };

    void work() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    text.append("hello " + i + "\n");
                }
            });
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried removing the sleep, but the window is still frozen in place until I reach the end of the loop. I can't move the asyncexec into the Worker.  asyncexec is a call on the SWT Display object and the Worker has no idea of the existence of the Display.

Comment: you could try passing `Display` into your `Worker` constructor so that it has context?

Comment: All i need to pass is the Text widget, and that is what I have done.

Comment: i was getting at, if your `Worker` is not aware of `Display`, you need to make it aware. Passing `Display` object into your `Worker` constructor would allow it to be used locally in that scope.

Comment: @casgage Just use `Display.getCurrent()` to get the display instance.

Comment: I do not need access to the Display.  Thankyou.

Comment: Using getCurrent does not change the behavior.  The window is still unresponsive and sometimes stops displaying lines until the loop ends and then they are all displayed at once ... not ideal behavior for what is in essence a log

Answer (score 1):

You are blocking UI by calling sleep() on UI Thread.

Use below method on `Display` if you want to update UI periodically

```
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.timerExec(int, Runnable)
```